# Why does this code have high cyclomatic complexity - or is it a bug in PHPMD in Jenkins?

Tags: php, jenkins, cyclomatic-complexity, phpmd

I'm trying to understand how Cyclomatic Complexity works and how I can avoid the warnings. Yes, I understand that the goal of writing code is not to avoid arbitrary warnings, but I'd at least like to know what's going on so I can decide if the code I'm seeing is good or bad.

I have a function that looks like:

```
protected function update($uuid, $data, $householdUuid, $androidId) {
    $household = $this->householdService->getHouseholdByUuid($householdUuid);

    $this->updatePeriod($household, $data);
    $this->updateNickname($household, $data, $androidId);
    $this->updateDateOrder($household, $data);
    $this->updateCurrency($household, $data);
    $this->updateAccounts($household, $data);

    $household->save();
    return $this->respondUpdated();
}
```

This gets flagged as having a cyclomatic complexity of 10. How is that possible? From [the documentation](http://phpmd.org/rules/index.html), I would count this as a 1. The only possibility is that PHPMD is descending down into the various method calls.

But if that's so, then I have no way to "fix" this method. Generally I would reduce the complexity of a method by extracting out smaller helper methods. This method got refactored into those various update() methods already, to eliminate a bunch of conditional updating that happens. The original method had a cyclomatic complexity of 10 as well, and the refactor did nothing.

Or maybe the problem is simpler -- I'm running PHPMD through a continuous integration set up with Jenkins. Could there be an issue where PHPMD is not using the most recent code? I have had somewhat similar issues where it will flag a class as having too many lines, after I had already refactored the class below the line number limit.

Comment: Seems like 10 = 1 (for the method) + 9 (for each '->') but I don't have an explanation.

Comment: Agree that it looks that way, but that's terrible and doesn't match the documentation.

Comment: It also still doesn't add up to 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might think that each function call is what is adding the +1 to the complexity, since it is technically a pass through the code, but it should not do this according to the documentation.  Even the definition for [Cyclomatic Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)  does not support this count.

I would think this is a bug in PHP Mess Detector, as the PHP_CodeSniffer complexity calculation does not give a 10 on this.

Comment: Even if that's what it was doing (which I highly doubt), it still wouldn't add up to 10.

Comment: As I said, I am not sure how you are getting this number in the PHP Mess Detector. Have you checked this with other tools, as I know PHP_CodeSniffer can do a similar count, and I believe PHPUnit/XDebug can produce a similar count in the documentation dump if enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I think its a bug. I haven't isolated it - but I collapsed one of my functions to {return false} and re-ran the jenkins job. I still had an NPath complexity of 4000 (ish). When I ran phpmd from the command line it correctly calculated it.

Looking into it a bit more, phpmd relies on pdepend, and pdepend does some caching. If you run pdepend directly you can specify "memory" or "file" caching in a config. But I don't know how or if its possible to influence how phpmd uses it. I thought perhaps restarting jenkins  would clear things - but it doesn't. Once my function has been marked as 'overly complex' - that seems to stay with it.

There are a few issues in the phpmd repo on github about caching. But its all a bit vague. If I isolate it as a reproducible bug and not some quirk of my setup, Ill submit a bug report.